# Background showing up in IE, but not in other browsers.. Java setting

Tags: wordpress, background

I'm working in wordpress theming and have a site set up that will detect an image from the database and then set that image to be the background of a div using simple javascript.

I have this set up on my test site, and it works perfectly on all browsers.

But now I have implemented the theme on the client site which has WP running WP-united, the background image only works in IE and no other browser. http://elder-geek.com/2009/09/interview-aaron-schurman-ceo-of-phantom-efx-2/

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: the test site is: http://www.heroicdreams.com/elder-geek/2009/09/02/interview-aaron-schurman-ceo-of-phantom-efx/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. there were spaces in the image save directories